# How we load data dynamically when we do scrolling with mouse to Devexpress XtraGrid in Winforms

Tags: winforms, load, xtragrid, devexpress-windows-ui

I want to load data to my Devexpress Xtragrid when scrolling is down on winform project. I searched everywhere but I didn't find anything. I don't want to use XPO and server mode. Can anybody help to me?

Answer (score 0):

See this [DevExpress Answer](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q329861).

```
DevExpress.XtraEditors.VScrollBar bar;
        foreach(Control ctrl in gridControl1.Controls)
            if (ctrl is DevExpress.XtraEditors.VScrollBar)  {
                bar = ctrl as DevExpress.XtraEditors.VScrollBar;
                bar.ValueChanged += new OnValueChanged;
                break;
            }
```

And according this [Smooth Scroll](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S131103) thread, DevExpress hasn't implemented this functionality in their `XtraGrid`.